# JSR 353 - Object Model : How to randomly access the object

Tags: java, json, api

**example.json**

```
{
    "user": "John",
    "age": 25,
    "gender": "Male",
    "title-name": ["title1","title2","title3"], 
    "address": 
    {
        "permanent-address":
        {
            "city": "Ohio",
            "country": "US"
        },
        "temporary-address":
        {
            "city": "Chicago",
            "country": "US"
        }

    }
}
```

How to access the `temporary-address` directly without moving to `address` object. 
Is it possible to access randomly? Explain how the tree is constructed for the given `json` file.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the usage of Jackson annotation for java.
This is a simple framework which allows you to convert Java object to / from JSON.

You will find toturiels here
https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

github project here:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations

A short explenation is that you will map your Json object with a POJO (Plain Old Java Object)
Based on you example.json we would have :

```
public class Example {

@JsonProperty("user")
private String name;

@JsonProperty("age")
private int age;

@JsonProperty("gender")
private String gender;

@JsonProperty("title-name")
private ArrayList<String> titleNames;

@JsonProperty("address")
private Adresses adresses;
...
```

please note the **Adresses** class for the last field. **Adresses** is a POJO containing information about 2 addresses:

```
public class Addresses {

@JsonProperty("permanent-address")
private Address permanenentAddress;

@JsonProperty("temporary-address")
private Address temporaryAddress;
...
```

And finally your Address sub element maped with a POJO class containing city and contry information:

```
 public class Address {

@JsonProperty("city")
private String city;

@JsonProperty("country")
private String country;
```

Once you maped your example.json with an Example.java POJO using

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Example data = mapper.readValue(exampleJsonObject, Example.class);
```

There you are!! you can acess TemporaryAdress information or any information in one line ;)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Example data = mapper.readValue(exampleJsonObject, Example.class);
Address address =  data.getAdresses().getTemporaryAdress();
```

Good luck